# How to batch import netCDF files into R and create a RasterStack

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster

I have >1000 netCDF files in the "data" folder of my working directory. These are rasters showing daily snow cover extent, with the date (yyyymmdd) captured in the file name.

```
nhtsd25e2_20120501_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120502_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120503_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120504_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120506_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120507_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120518_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120520_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120521_v01r01.nc
nhtsd25e2_20120522_v01r01.nc
```

When I open a singe file, I find that the name of the data field is 'Merged.Snow.Cover.Extent'

```
library(raster)
snow <- raster("./data/nhtsd25e2_20120522_v01r01.nc")
view(snow)
```

What I would like to do (and don't have the faintest idea of where to start) is to batch import the netCDF files from my "data" folder and create a RasterStack.

The caveat is that I only want to import netCDF files for snow cover between Feb 1 and July 1 of each year (so where month-day >= "0201" but <= "0701", and where year doesn't matter.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Get a the filenames with `list.files`

```
ff <- list.files(pattern="\\.nc$")
```

Here your example files

```
ff <- c("nhtsd25e2_20120501_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120502_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120503_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120504_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120506_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120507_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120518_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120520_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120521_v01r01.nc", "nhtsd25e2_20120522_v01r01.nc")
```

Extract dates/months

```
dates <- substr(ff, 11, 18)
months <- as.integer(substr(dates, 5, 6))
```

Subset to Feb to June (you can add July 1 back in if you want it)

```
 f <- ff[months > 1 & months < 7]
```

Create a RasterStack

```
 x <- stack(f)
```

Or

```
 x <- lapply(f, raster)
 x <- stack(f)
```